# Webservice Serialization

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, xml-serialization, asmx

I'm currently setting up a generic webservice that takes in credentials, an environment and tries to log a person in. It also returns a collection with return values that matter to for the specific environments.

The problem I'm having is when I want to return part of an object graph in the `returnvalues` node.

Since return values is a `Dictionairy<string, object>` it has no clue how to serialize the object graph.

So I thought I'd serialize this into a `MemoryStream`, load this into an `XmlDocument` and then serialize this.

How ever that gives the foloowing:

```
<returnvalues>
 <returnvalue>
  <key>defendant</key> 
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <something xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    </something>
  </value> 
 </returnvalue>
<returnvalues>
```

What I'd like to get is the following:

```
<returnvalues>
 <returnvalue>
  <key>defendant</key> 
  <value>
    <something></something>
  </value> 
  </returnvalue>
<returnvalues>
```

Is this possible? and if so, how do I go about making my response dynamic in such a way? Should I use a different type for my `returnvalues` node?

I should note this is in .NET 2.0 so i don't have access to any fancy WCF bits :(

Comment: Wow, .NET 2.0? It was released in 2005. Six years old!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do special things when Xml-serializing a generic Dictionary.

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx) shows you how to do it.

In your case, you'd need to make the return value of your WebMethod a `SerializableDictionary<T1,T2>`.

Comment: But that would require me to specify T2, what i would like is to be able to shove any object i want into T2. Without having to change the definition of the collection. This so i can keep the return object identical for all different login environments. Basically currently i sometimes return a int, or a string or what ever in the current collection, which works like a charm. However in the future i'd like to be able to return a (part of a) object graph. Without making any changes in the return object.